# Paypal Billing Agreement with Do DIrect Payment/CreditCard

Tags: paypal

I have been working on Reference Transactions. Is it possible to create a Billing Agreement using Do Direct Payment as it is not returning any token in the response ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no billing agreement that gets created with the DoDirectPayment API.  In order to charge the buyer again, all you have to do is make the API call for a reference transaction and pass over the previous successful transaction id.  Express Checkout would be the API that you would want to use if you want to set up a billing agreement.